# Math Differentiation Limits

Tags: limits, derivatives

$$\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{2x^2 + 7x-15}{x-3}$$

What I Simplified

Step 1 : $\frac{2x^2 + 10x -3x -15}{x-3}$

Step 2 : $\frac{2x(x + 5)-3(x + 5)}{x-3}$

Step 3 : $\frac{(2x - 3)(x + 5)}{x-3}$

but unable to move further.. im thinking either the question is wrong or there is some trick which im unable to understand thanx in advance

Comment: Looks like a mistake in the question. The function seems to be $\dfrac{2x^2 + 7x-15}{x-3}$, and the denominator $2x^2 + 7x - 15$ doesn't have a zero in $x = 3$. Or possibly, you are expected to say that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: the second part

Comment: In case you're confused, when Daniel says 'denominator', he means 'numerator'.

Comment: Oops, my edit mistake, feel free to correct it.

Comment: thix question ix from frank s Budnik Applied Math Section 15.1

Comment: i dont know how to edit thix u plz re edit it..

Comment: @Donkey_2009: note the step 1 that needs to be fixed as well

Comment: It simply goes to infinite isn't it?

Comment: ys it seems.. but i was thinking that may b im wrong.. :(

Comment: @ Rummy Khan: To find out how to edit click on the help link at the top right of the page, search 'maths symbols' and click on 'our MathJax quick reference page.' or if you see something in someone else's comment or answer or question you want to use, right click on it, then select Show Math As > Text Commands and copy and paste it to your comment/answer/question

Comment: thanx i have found the answer... :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $x$ approaches to 3 from above, we can write is as $x \to 3^{+}$, then the denominator also appraoches to 0 form above, or $x-3 \to 0^{+}$.

$$\lim_{x\to 3^{+}} \frac{2x^2 + 7x-15}{x-3} = \infty$$

But if $x$ approaches to 3 from below we get that the denominator also approaches o from below or $x-3 \to 0^{-}$

$$\lim_{x\to 3^{-}} \frac{2x^2 + 7x-15}{x-3} = -\infty$$

To make it even more simplier, if $x \to 3^{+}$, then the denominator's value will be a positive number very, very, very close to $0.$ While if $x \to 3^{-}$, then the denominator's value will be a negative number very, very, very close to $0$. And we know that no matter from which side we approach the numerator will always have a positive value.

So we proved that the one-sided limits have different values, so that implies that a two-sided limit doesn't exist.